# PHP: SoapClient Response code from HTTP headers

Tags: php, http, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to extract the Soap response's HTTP status code.
So for instance i have :

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$client->__setSoapHeaders(
    new SoapHeader(
        $nameSpace,
        'Security',
        $secHeaderValue,
        true
    )
);

// The actual call
$response = $client->Complete($paramswebservice)
```

So now i'm getting the response headers, this way :

```
$responseHeaders = $client->__getLastResponseHeaders();
var_dump($responseHeaders);
```

This is the result of the vardump : a string formatted this way (web browser - page source code)

[image]

**What i am doing right now to extract the http status code '200' :**

```
/**
 * Returns the HTTP Status code of $response
 * @param string $response
 * @return string
 */
function extract_response_http_code($response) {
    $tmp = explode('\n', $response);
    $array = explode(' ', $tmp[0]);

    return $array[1];
}
```

I really don't like this solution. I would like a more robust / consistent one. Any suggestions ?

**EDIT 1**

As asked in the comments :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 1315
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 30 Mar 2017 08:52:15 GMT
```

Comment: Can you please provide `print_r($response)` instead of Image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/764240)

```
<?php
$result="HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 1315
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 30 Mar 2017 08:52:15 GMT";
preg_match("/HTTP\/\d\.\d\s*\K[\d]+/", $result,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 200
)
```

Comment: Your solution is better. But i'm still wondering, there's no SoapClient methods or any other way to get that http code ? With something  close to getResponseHttpCode() or such ?

Comment: I have researched for it. But `__getLastResponseHeaders` returns string, for which i think `preg_match` can be good solution